# Notification send to multiple device in android java using Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

is there any way to send a notification to multiple device when a button is clicked in android(java) using Firebase.?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow.
Yes, you can achive it by suscribing your users to a topic.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging

Comment: I have explained in one of my **[tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0AmXOWOam729bC47v0d0Ohee)** step by step, how you can send **[notifications](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6RzB4HXzQyA&t=3s&list=PLn2n4GESV0AmXOWOam729bC47v0d0Ohee&index=17)** to specific users using `Cloud Firestore` and `Node.js`. You can also take a look at my answer from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48298993/push-notifications-on-content-change/48299840)**.

Comment: Thankyou. it really helped.

Answer (score 1):

From this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39391468/how-to-send-firebase-push-notification-to-specific-group-of-user-for-android) and [Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging) :

Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) topic messaging allows you to send a message to multiple devices that have opted in to a particular topic.

From Server side you need to set up for specif topic i.e a group of user like this:

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=AIzaSyZ-1u...0GBYzPu7Udno5aA

{
  "to": "/topics/news",
  "data": {
    "message": "This is a Firebase Cloud Messaging Topic Message!",
   }
}
```

"/topics/news" This will send notification to group of peopl

Comment: Thanks for the sharing the knowledge. i will try and check this out.